# Could not create directory '/h//.ssh'

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am trying to perform a git pull to pull a project and I am getting an error stating: Could not create directory '/h//.ssh'.

My SSH key is located in C/Projects/xxx but I am not sure if the error is due git not looking in the right direction for the key or if it's something else.

What is the error and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Your ssh key is normally located in your user folder inside `.ssh`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes but we have created on in the projects folder